# SAS DDE excel save as without warning

Tags: excel, sas, dde

I want to save as the excel file using SAS DDE. Anyone know how to turn off the warnings from excel if the file is exist?

Below is the code:

```
FILENAME DCMDS DDE'EXCEL|SYSTEM';
DATA _null_;
    FILE dcmds;
    PUT "[save.as(""D:\Reports\sme_fwd.xls"")]";
    PUT "[file.close(FALSE,FALSE)]";
RUN;
```

In VBA we can set `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to turn off the warning, but I don't know what the similar syntax in SAS DDE.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can save instead of save.as if you're working with the same workbook. You can find the DDE references on the Microsoft home page here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128185

```
 put '[error(false)]';
```

Comment: Hi Reese, I've tried that code. The warning of file exist still there. So I've to click every time run the code. Thanks

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Are you saving this file over another older file, or have you opened this file specifically and manipulating it? Basically can you simply save instead of save.as?

Comment: I opened excel which already have template for report. After put the data from sas thru dde, i'm saving it over another older file. Basically i can save it to new file, but our scheduler already set to read specific file name. So i have to replacing it with new data every day.

Comment: Easy work around, I guess I'd recommend versioning out the old file by renaming it and then saving as new file. How do you know if the process failed and you're working with an old file? I'll take a more detailed look when back at the office tomorrow if someone hasn't answered already :)

Comment: Yeah you right..that is the easiest workaround. But i'm still curious how to turn off the warning :D

Comment: Yes i did. The warning still there. I'll try it again on monday. Thanks, Reese

Comment: An error occur if I put that code "ERROR: DDE session not ready.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.". I think I will use your workaround above. Thanks, @Reese

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to save the file without warning messages

```
put '[Save.As(" '"' "&savepath" '\' "&savename" '")]' "';
put '[File.Close(false)]';
```